# Postgresql: Issue with interval & daylight saving

Tags: postgresql

(PostgreSQL 9.4.8)

I wrote a simple SQL functions to group records for statistics by interval (group by 1day, 1hour, 63minutes etc ...)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.timestamp_bucket(startdate timestamp with time zone, step interval, datetime timestamp with time zone) RETURNS timestamptz 
AS 
$BODY$ 
SELECT startdate::timestamptz + 
        (
            (
                floor(
                    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (datetime - startdate::timestamp)) / 
                        EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM step)
                )::integer * EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM step)
            )  || ' seconds' 
        )::interval;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE COST 100;
```

Samples:

Grouped by '1day'

```
$ select timestamp_bucket('2017-10-29 00:00:00+02'::timestamptz, '1day'::interval, '2017-10-29 00:01:02'::timestamptz);
    timestamp_bucket    
------------------------
 2017-10-29 00:00:00+02
```

Grouped by "6minutes"

```
$ select timestamp_bucket('2017-09-17 00:00:00+02'::timestamptz, '6minutes'::interval, '2017-09-18 13:10:02'::timestamptz);
timestamp_bucket    
------------------------
 2017-09-18 13:06:00+02
```

But it doesn't work when there is daylight saving ...

In France the timezone changed from '+02' to '+01' during the night between 28th and 29th of october 2017
The result is now:

```
select timestamp_bucket('2017-10-29 00:00:00+02'::timestamptz, '1day'::interval, '2017-10-30 09:01:02'::timestamptz);
    timestamp_bucket    
------------------------
 2017-10-29 23:00:00+01
```

And i can check this with:

```
# select '2017-10-29 00:00:00+02'::timestamptz +  '24:00:00'::interval;
        ?column?        
------------------------
 2017-10-29 23:00:00+01
```

But

```
select '2017-10-29 00:00:00+02'::timestamptz +  '1day'::interval;
        ?column?        
------------------------
 2017-10-30 00:00:00+01
```

Ok, the 29th has 25hours, but is there a way to fix the function to have
`timestamp_bucket('2017-10-01 00:00:00+02'::timestamptz, '1day'::interval, '2017-10-30 09:01:02'::timestamptz) = '2017-10-30 00:00:00+01'`

Comment: What about discarding timezone before interval calculation? E.g.: `select '2017-10-29 00:00:00+02'::timestamp +  '24:00:00'::interval;`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @michel.milezzi I post the solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.timestamp_bucket(startdate timestamp with time zone, step interval, datetime timestamp with time zone) RETURNS timestamptz AS 
$BODY$ 
SELECT (startdate::timestamp + 
        (
            (
                floor(
                    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (datetime::timestamp - startdate::timestamp)) / 
                        EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM step)
                )::integer * EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM step)
            )  || ' seconds' 
        )::interval)::timestamptz;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE COST 100;
```

I also try converting '24hours' in day, with something like, but i don't like it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.timestamp_bucket(startdate timestamp with time zone, step interval, datetime timestamp with time zone) RETURNS timestamptz 
AS 
$BODY$ 
WITH partial AS (
    SELECT (
            (
                floor(
                    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (datetime - startdate::timestamp)) / 
                        EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM step)
                )::integer * EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM step)
            )  || ' seconds' 
        )::interval AS _interval
)
SELECT startdate::timestamptz + 
    CASE WHEN _interval >= '24:00:00'::interval THEN
        (
            EXTRACT(YEARS FROM _interval) || 'years ' || 
            EXTRACT(MONTHS FROM _interval) || 'months ' ||
            (EXTRACT(DAYS FROM _interval) + (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM _interval) / 24) ) || 'days ' ||
            (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM _interval)::integer % 24) || 'hours ' ||
            EXTRACT(MINUTES FROM _interval) || 'minutes ' ||
            EXTRACT(SECONDS FROM _interval) || 'seconds ' ||
            EXTRACT(MILLISECONDS FROM _interval) || 'millisecond ' ||
            EXTRACT(MICROSECONDS FROM _interval) || 'microseconds'
        )::interval
    ELSE _interval END

FROM partial;
        ;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE COST 100;
```